# Are API's Just an example of Abstraction or is there more to it

Tags: java, api, oop, abstraction

Big Packages Like twitter Provides Developers with APIs These APIs allow them to have limited access of the functions of their packages.

The implementation of functions we have access is hidden so is it safe to say APIs are just an example of Abstraction??

Answer (score 2):

The "I" in API stands for "interface". An interface is something that you interact with by providing input and receiving output. Abstraction is an idea, just that, an idea without a specific implementation. Look at Java abstract methods and classes. They are "ideas", if we may say so, that each one of us can implement in a different manner. Having said that and looking again at the API, we API consumers, have no say on the implementation of the API functions. We feed it some input and get some output, or in other words, we interface with it.

Is this an example of abstraction? Not to me.